# Invalid Signature Identity Provider Event Log for Self Signed Certificate SAML Sp Initiated Web Browser SSO Profile

Tags: authentication, saml, certificates

I am implementing Service Provider component of SAML protocol and I am aiming to achieve SP Initiated Web Browser SSO Profile.I have configured my domain

I dint add my self signed digital certificate to my Connected APP.I am getting the Success status SAMLResponse and everything is fine.

When I tried to add my self signed digital certificate (created using keytool command of java`keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias ss3 -keystore ss3.jks -storepass 123456  -validity 365 -keysize 1024     AND 
keytool -export -alias ss3 -file ss3.crt -keystore ss3.jks (to export the certificate)`).

I am getting the AuthnFailed Response Message.
When I checked the Identity Provider Event log INVALID SIGNATURE

Could anyone please suggest me Where did I go wrong ??

I also validate the Signature in my signed AUTHNREQUEST MEssage using openSaml libaray Java code. what type of digital certificates does salesforce accept? Can I give Self signed certificate ? any other constraints ?

Also Verfied the public key content of my certificate and ds:X509Certificate.They both matches.